# Guess My Number, Classic Edition

Tags: python, beginner, number-guessing-game

I am learning Python at present, from several books. I am new to programming and I need assistance with knowing when my code is written with good form and style - I want to ingrain the habit of writing good clean code, which would be accepted as thus by other programmers. This is a code example from the book *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner* by Michael Dawson, which I have altered in several ways - a game which picks a random number and asks the player to guess that number:

```
# Alex Grattan 
# 8/10/14

# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low
# or right on the money

import random

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1

# guessing loop
while guess != the_number:
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")

    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
    if tries == 5:
        print "You failed to guess in time!"
        break
    if guess == the_number:
        print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

The code works, however, I feel it is slightly 'bloated' and messy. How would a more experienced programmer change my code?

Comment: You're asking the user to guess a number within a certain amount of tries while telling him he needs to guess it in as few tries as possible. That's not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mixing Python 2 and 3

The program is correct in neither Python 2 nor Python 3.

Your program fails to run at all in Python 3, due to the lack of parentheses when calling

```
print "You failed to guess in time!"
```

Also, the `raw_input()` function does not exist in Python 3.

On the other hand, it's not quite correct under Python 2 either.  These `print` statements

```
print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
```

would be interpreted as requests to print tuples… complete with parentheses and commas.

### Initialization

The number of allowed guesses, 5, is buried in the middle of your program, and should be defined in an obvious place near the top.

The bounds, 1 and 100, are each hard-coded twice.  That is a maintenance pitfall, should you ever need to change the upper bound.  Again, these special numbers should be defined just once in an obvious place.

### Loop

The `"Take a guess"` prompting statement is written twice.  It should be moved inside the loop, at the top of the loop.

@MasayukiFujita and @MathiasPanda have the right idea, I think, to use the count rather than the correctness as the loop condition.  I would go a step further and suggest that counting loops in Python would be more idiomatically written using `for counter in range(…)`.

To distinguish between the winning and losing condition without using a boolean variable or retesting the correctness of the guess, you can take advantage of an obscure Python language feature: [an `else` clause on a loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).  The `else` clause is executed only when the loop terminates "naturally", rather than due to a `break`.

### Newline management

You'll have a better time printing nice output if you make a habit of always putting your newlines at the *end* of print statements.

### Suggested solution

Here is a program that works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import random

BOUNDS = (1, 100)
TRIES_ALLOWED = 5

the_number = random.randint(*BOUNDS)

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!\n")
print("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d." % BOUNDS)
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

for tries in range(TRIES_ALLOWED):
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Higher...")
    else:
        print("You guessed it! The number was %d" % (the_number))
        print("And it only took you %d tries!\n\n" % (tries + 1))
        break
else:
    print("You failed to guess in time!\n\n")

# Admittedly a contorted way to write a statement that works in both Python 2 and 3...
try:
    input("Press the enter key to exit.")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: You'll allow 5 attempts whereas the OP only allows 4 (might be intentional, might not).

Comment: @Ben The original code also prompts for five guesses.

Comment: It breaks on the 5th guess before determining whether the guess is correct; I suspect it's wrong, but it'll only allow 4.

Answer (score 4):

You can kill off the if/else print in the while loop by using a one liner:

```
print "Lower..." if guess > the_number else "Higher"
```

Can also get rid of the last raw_input, as it is just annoying:

```
raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Can also get rid of the three print calls in the top and replace it with 1 multiline print:

```
print("""\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.
Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n""")
```

which leaves us with:

```
import random

print("""\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.
Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n""")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1

# guessing loop
while guess != the_number:
    print "Lower..." if guess > the_number else "Higher"

    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1

    if tries == 5:
        print "You failed to guess in time!"
        break

    if guess == the_number:
        print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not an experienced programmer so someone will probably have a better solution.. However, this is how I would have written this game. I simply separated the 'tries' loop from the printing of the results.

```
import random

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 0
maxTries=5
win = False

# guessing loop
while tries < maxTries:
    tries +=1
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    if guess == the_number:
        win = True
        break
    elif guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")

if win:
    print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
    print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
else:
    print "You failed to guess in time!"
```

Comment: I am glad to see differing ways of writing something. It can only improve my skills. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very simple code, so there isn't much room for improvements. If I had to change it though, I would change the `while` part to:

```
while tries < 5:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Higher...") #Your original code would show correct answer as "Higher..."
    elif guess == the_number:
        break

if tries == 5:
    print "You failed to guess in time!"
if guess == the_number:
    print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
    print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Again, since the code is so simple, there isn't much room for improvements.

Comment: I am glad to see differing ways of writing something. It can only improve my skills. Thanks.

Comment: There's a bug where if you guess correctly on the fifth turn, it will print both `You failed to guess in time!` and `You guessed it!`.

Comment: You shouldn't get to the fifth try because the while loop stops at try 4.

Answer (score 2):

You should catch the `ValueError`, when the user enters a value which cannot be converted to an integer.

```
try:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Please, enter a number value!)
    continue
```

It is better to keep that part inside the while loop and catch the error only in one place as you did (See @jsanc623's code, where the error can occur twice.)

```
import random

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = 0
tries = 0
max_tries = 5

# guessing loop
print(the_number)
while guess != the_number:
    if tries == max_tries:
        print("You failed to guess in time!")
        break

    try:
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numeric value")
        continue

    tries += 1

    if guess == the_number:
        print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
        break

    print("Lower...") if guess > the_number else print("Higher...")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```