# "Guess My Number", Alternative Edition

Tags: python, number-guessing-game

This is an alternative edition of a game I modified the code for. See:

[Guess My Number, Classic Edition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65140/guess-my-number-classic-edition)

I seek advice on best practice. Tips, tricks, and suggestions, all welcome:

```
# Alex Grattan
# 9/10/14

# This is an alternative version of the "Guess My Number Game". 
# The Computer now has the role of guessing a number chosen by the player.
# The Computer emulates the expected behaviour of a player - 
# The Computer will not choose a number higher or lower than one already chosen.

import random

BOUNDS = (1, 100)
THE_NUMBER = int(input("\t\tPick a number between %r and %r:\n " % BOUNDS))
TRIES_ALLOWED = 7
PREVIOUS_GUESSES = {'Min': BOUNDS[0], 'Max': BOUNDS[1]}
TRIES = 0

print("""\n\t\tThe Computer will now attempt to guess your number in a minimum of attempts:\n
\t\tO.K. Computer, you have %d gusses. Proceed!\n""") % TRIES_ALLOWED

for x in range(TRIES_ALLOWED):

    GUESS = random.randint(PREVIOUS_GUESSES.get('Min'), PREVIOUS_GUESSES.get('Max'))
    print ("\t\t\t %d\n") % GUESS
    TRIES += 1

    if GUESS > THE_NUMBER:
        print("\t\tSorry Computer. Your guess of %d was too high.\n\t\tTake a lower guess:\n") % GUESS
        PREVIOUS_GUESSES['Max'] = GUESS - 1

    elif GUESS < THE_NUMBER:
        print("\t\tSorry Computer. Your guess of %d was too low.\n\t\tTake a higher guess:\n") % GUESS
        PREVIOUS_GUESSES['Min'] = GUESS + 1

    else:
        GUESS == THE_NUMBER
        print("""\tCongratulations Computer, you guessed it! The number was %d
        \t\tAnd it only took you %d tries!\n""") % (THE_NUMBER, TRIES)
        break
else:    
    print("""Sorry Computer; you failed to guess the number!
    The number I chose was %d""") % THE_NUMBER
```

Comment: I've just noticed; the variable 'PREVIOUS_GUESSES', should be changed to 'GUESS_BOUNDARIES'.

Comment: Are you also looking for any suggestions to the strategy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'strategy'; but yes, sure. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

A common practice is to reserve all capital names for constants. As these variables change during the execution of the program, so they should be lowercased instead: `PREVIOUS_GUESSES`, `TRIES`, `GUESS`.

---

Inside this else, you have a pointless statement:

> ```
> else:
>     GUESS == THE_NUMBER  # <-- just delete this line... or at least comment it out
> ```

---

Using the `.get` method of dictionaries, for example in `PREVIOUS_GUESSES.get('Min')` and `PREVIOUS_GUESSES.get('Max')` can be useful when you're not sure if the keys (`Min`, `Max` in this example) exist,
and if they don't exist you don't want a `KeyError` raised.
In this script these keys are guaranteed to exist,
so you can safely (and consistently) use `PREVIOUS_GUESSES['Min']` and `PREVIOUS_GUESSES['Max']` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using Python 3, **DO NOT** use the `input()` function. It'll interpret whatever they enter as code. Instead, use `raw_input`.